# Error when selecting colum names from table in MySQL information schema

Tags: mysql, sql, select, information-schema

I am trying to get a list of the column names from a specific table in MySQL. I am running:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = `test 2.2`
    AND table_schema = test
```

The database is called `test` and the table name is `test 2.2` and the rest of the syntax looks correct. However I keep receiving the error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'test 2.2' in 'where clause'

Is there another way that I can do what I want and/or how do I get around this error?

Comment: You are wrapping the value inside `. You should use '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object names (in this case: a table name) are stored in the information schema as string literals, so they should be queried with single quotes (`'`):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'test 2.2' AND table_schema = 'test'
-- Here -----------^--------^--------------------^----^
```

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes and not backticks for strings

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'test 2.2'
  AND table_schema = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = "test 2.2"
    AND table_schema = "test"
```

Or, Why don't you just describe the table.

```
desc `test 2.2`;
```

Comment: Because I am trying to get a list of column names that I can pull from in a program. `SHOW COLUMNS` and `DESCRIBE` both give me `Type, NULL, Default, etc.` information that I do not want in my program.